# Idiomatic Scala solution for the Dutch national flag problem

Tags: scala, functional-programming, quicksort, side-effects, dutch-national-flag-problem

I'm solving the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) in Scala, and came up with the following code:

```
def dutchNationalFlag[T](a: Array[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) = {
  def sort(lo: Int, hi: Int): Unit = {
    Stream.iterate((lo, hi, lo + 1)) { acc =>
      val (lt, gt, i) = acc

      if (ordering.lt(a(i), a(lt))) {
        swap(lt, i, a)
        (lt + 1, gt, i + 1)
      } else if (ordering.gt(a(i), a(gt))) {
        swap(gt, i, a)
        (lt, gt - 1, i)
      } else {
        (lt, gt, i + 1)
      }
    }
      .takeWhile(acc => acc._2 >= acc._3)
      .lastOption
      .foreach { acc =>
        val (lt, gt, _) = acc

        sort(lo, lt - 1)
        sort(gt + 1, hi)
      }
  }

  sort(0, a.length - 1)
}
```

For performance reasons, I want to modify the existing array, not create a new one. The above code works, but it has an obvious side-effect in `swap` being called from `iterate`, which would be questionable in a purely functional style code. I considered replacing `swap` with a method reference that's executed later in `foreach`, something along the lines of Haskell IO, but as you can imagine, doing so would make the code somewhat complicated.

Other ideas?

Comment: Mutable operations make no sense in the context of pure functional programming. If you're not in a situation where you can do pure functional programming and trust the compiler to optimize, then there's little reason to adhere to the stricter standards. If you save up all the swaps and apply them at the end, that still incurs the memory overhead you were trying to avoid in the first place, while gaining none of the benefits of pure FP.

Comment: @Ethan The way I see it, I’ve a problem I’d like to solve in an efficient manner. If pure FP makes that difficult, I’ve no reason to subscribe to the cool kids’ club. That said, I’m not convinced that pure FP code can’t be equally efficient as imperative.

Comment: There are efficient, concise pure FP solutions to this. They don't do it by calling swaps on mutable arrays. And any solution that does so by definition can not be pure FP. Forcing an answer to generate the array swaps means you won't get an efficient FP answer.

Comment: @Ethan "efficient, concise pure FP solutions" is exactly what I'm looking for. Please show, not tell.

Answer (score 0):

The "mutate the array in place for performance reasons" is a classic issue when translating an imperative algorithm to a pure-functional one, but there are a bunch of ways around it if you get a bit more clever with data structures. For instance, what if you represented your array like this:

```
class RearrangedArray[A](elements: Array[A], indexMap: Map[Int, Int] = Map.empty) {
  def apply(i: Int): A = elements(indexMap.getOrElse(i, i))
  def swap(i: Int, j: Int): RearrangedArray = {
    val newMap = indexMap + (i -> indexMap.getOrElse(j, j)) + (j -> indexMap.getOrElse(i, i))
    new RearrangedArray(elements, newMap)
  }
  def toArray: Array[A] = {
    (0 until elements.size).map(apply).toArray
  }
}
```

Note that it's fully immutable, uses O(n) memory, swaps and lookups happen in constant time... all the same performance characteristics, but you can create a new one on each iteration and pass it along with your indexes to make this fully referentially transparent. Rather than mutating the array, have all of your functions take one of these as a parameter, and return a new one as a result.

Comment: Could you update your answer to show how `RearrangedArray` would be used with the code in my question? If I understood your idea, I could just pass an index map around containing the latest indices of the array. For simple `Int` arrays, this solution takes 3 times the amount of memory, `O(n)` for the array, and `2 * O(n)` for the map.

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I would be inclined to solve the problem in

```
def sort[T](low: T, high: T)(items: List[T])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T])=
{
  val groupedItems = items.groupBy
  {
    _ match
    {
      case item if ordering.lt(item,low) => 0
      case item if ordering.gt(item,high) => 2
      case _ => 1
    }
  }
  groupedItems(0) ++ groupedItems(1) ++ groupedItems(2)
}
```

This will likely be less efficient than writing Java or C style code. Generally, this is OK. The Scala compiler is pretty good at optimizing things, and the performance is generally close enough that you won't really notice a difference. If you are planning to do this on large quantities of data, the Scala version has the advantage that it's already a parallel algorithm. If you call `.par` on the input list, you get a parallel collection that will run the operations across multiple cores/threads. If you change `List[T]` to `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]`, then the code is ready to run on a distributed cluster with dozens of machines.

Comment: The code above groups the items, but not sort them; You're missing the recursive calls.